# Background white color removing of .jpg image using css

Tags: css, jpeg

Is it possible to remove background white color using css of this image http://www.quickybuy.com/products/1/pcH8cew66V1372346341/1.jpg ??

Comment: this is madness and .jpg not have a alpha channel

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not a tool that is capable of editing an image. It is a style sheet language which is used to describe the presentation of HTML elements in a web page. You can do that with any image editing tool like Photoshop.

Still you can crop the image from the sides using CSS but i would not recommend it as the result may not be perfect because of rounded image of phone.(Image you posted)

Before you ask a question, make sure that you at least know the basics of it else you will be downvoted to such an extent that you may not be able to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit a photo or an image you have to use the appropriate programs such as photoshop. Style sheets, create an image, change the background color, create rounded edges, but they can not change a picture!

Answer (score 0):

We can't save a .Jpg file without background color. whenever we save a transparent image to .jpg, by default it uses white color as its background.you can use .png images, or use any Photo editing software to remove the background and save it as .png instead of the .jpg file.